# file writing programm randomly exits without errors

Tags: java, file-io, scheduled-tasks

currently i'm trying to write to a txt-file with Java's Files-Class. This task should be done every 5 seconds and is scheduled by an ScheduledExecutorService. For some time it's doing it's job propperly but after a random time my program exits without any warnings, errors or so. I have tried to reproduce this but it seems to occur very random. I've also tried to use a PrintWriter but that lead randomly to the same behaviour.

Thanks in advance!!!

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FileWritingClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new Runnable() {
                long i;
                String str = "";
                Path path = Paths.get("TestFile.txt");

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    str = LocalTime.now().toString() + ": still alive after " + i + " times.";
                    i++;

                    try
                    {   
                        System.out.println(str);
                        Files.write(path, (str + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            500 /* Startdelay */,
            5000 /* period */,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );        
    }
}
```

Comment: By random you mean "i" is different each time it stops? Do you see any files starting with "hs_err_pid" in the same directory?

Comment: Just a comment; 1) `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. 2) `Paths.get` should not be relative (probably isn't). 3) IOException should be logged. 4) 5) a logger with for instance circularly numbered log files would be nice too; System.out.prinln would be obsolete.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul yes "i" is different everytime. No, theres no such file. Only my TestFile.txt

Comment: `Here is my simplified code`. I've just tested it and it works fine for me. Can you show the full code?

Comment: @JoopEggen i left the sout in there because i'm running it in eclipse for test purposes and wanted to get a feedback without opening the file just to check if its still running. Unfortuneatly the console does not display any thrown exceptions when the program stops thats why i dont understand why it stopped i the first place.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov yes it works. But the thing is, that it stops sometimes after a few hours and sometimes after minutes for no reason without any thrown exceptions. Actually thats the full code on which i wanted to investigate this problem.

Comment: One would more guess that there is an issue with available threads. Maybe a motivation to add JavaMelody or an other monitoring tool.

Comment: @plasticmirror, there're two reasons I'm aware of which can cause the program to stop. 1) An `IOException` is thrown. Log it (f.e. in the same file, and you'll see it). 2) Something external unrelated to the JVM stops it.

Comment: @JoopEggen ok, i'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Do you have any ideas on how to track external influences which can cause the JVM to stop?

Comment: It is more likely to be an uncaught Exception than random system event. Please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376004/9569292

Comment: @PhilBart, first of all, I don't think it's something external, it's just one of the possible reasons. I don't have one "go and do it solution" to track external influences, cause it depends on the OS and the environment. I'd suggest you doing a proper logging. Most probably it's just uncaught exception which causes the JVM to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The `Executor` is swallowing Exceptions other than `IOException`. Catch `Throwable` instead of just `IOException`.

The `Executor` fails when it encounters some Exception other than IOException. The VM is still alive, but the `Executor` has failed.

Here's some code to try:

```
                    try
                    {   
                        System.out.println(str);
                        Files.write(path, (str + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                        if(new Random().nextBoolean()) {
                            System.out.println("Here we go.");
                            throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("The show must go on...");
                    }
```

Note how I give a 50/50 chance to throw an uncaught exception after the write (just for quick failure).
If you remove the second `catch`, it will just stop printing.
With the `catch`, the output becomes:

```
12:46:00.780250700: still alive after 0 times.
12:46:05.706355500: still alive after 1 times.
Here we go.
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Uncaught at
KeepaTokenRecorder$FileWritingClass$1.run(KeepaTokenRecorder.java:89)
    at [...]
The show must go on...
12:46:15.705899200: still alive after 3 times.
```